# How do u get a visa to visit Canada whiles in the US on B1-B2 visa

Tags: visas

I am visiting the US from Ghana and would want to visit Canada also. Can I apply for a Canadian visa from the US whiles on B1-B2 visa? If so how long will it take to process ?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Processing times for temporary resident visa applications processed by visa offices outside Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/temp/visitors.asp) page, the Los Angeles office takes 42 days, New York 52 days. My understanding of these things is: you can always apply for a temporary visitor visa wherever you are. (Just for completeness sake, for other kinds of visas this is not true.) I can't find the reference to this on the CIC website but this thread on the [Canadavisa forum](http://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/applying-for-a-visitor-visa-while-a-visitor-in-another-country-t166455.0.html) definitely agrees.